# missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' when trying to create a button

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a backspace button for my calculator which deletes only one integer at a time, however when I run the program I have the problem that I am "missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'". I have done lots of searching and I haven't found a working solution. Thanks in advance :)

```
# Calculator

# Imports
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

#Declaring Functions
def btnClick(numbers):
     global operator
     operator=operator + str(numbers)
     text_Input.set(operator)
     
def btnClearDisplay():
    global operator
    operator=''
    text_Input.set('')
    
def btnEquals():
    global operator
    sumup=str(eval(operator))
    text_Input.set(sumup)
    operator=''
    
def backspace_b(self):
    self.current = self.current[0:len(self.current) -1]

# Setting up the GUI
window=Tk()
window.title('Calculator')# Setting the title as Calculator
text_Input = StringVar()
operator=''

# Text box
txtDisplay = Entry(window, font=('arial', 20,'bold'), textvariable=text_Input, bd=30, insertwidth=4, bg='powder blue', justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)# This sets up font, font size, text input, how big the textbox is going to be and what the borders will look like

# Setting up the buttons
btn7=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='7',command=lambda:btnClick(7), bg='powder blue').grid(row=1, column=0)
btn8=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='8',command=lambda:btnClick(8), bg='powder blue').grid(row=1, column=1)
btn9=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='9',command=lambda:btnClick(9), bg='powder blue').grid(row=1, column=2)
btnAddition=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='+',command=lambda:btnClick('+'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=1, column=3)

#===============================================================================================================================

btn4=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='4',command=lambda:btnClick(4), bg='powder blue').grid(row=2, column=0)
btn5=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='5',command=lambda:btnClick(5), bg='powder blue').grid(row=2, column=1)
btn6=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='6',command=lambda:btnClick(6), bg='powder blue').grid(row=2, column=2)
btnSubtraction=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='-',command=lambda:btnClick('-'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=2, column=3)

#===============================================================================================================================

btn1=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='1',command=lambda:btnClick(1), bg='powder blue').grid(row=3, column=0)
btn2=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='2',command=lambda:btnClick(2), bg='powder blue').grid(row=3, column=1)
btn3=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='3',command=lambda:btnClick(3), bg='powder blue').grid(row=3, column=2)
btnMultiplication=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='*',command=lambda:btnClick('*'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=3, column=3)

#===============================================================================================================================

btn0=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='0',command=lambda:btnClick(0), bg='powder blue').grid(row=4, column=0)
btnClear=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='C',command=btnClearDisplay, bg='powder blue').grid(row=4, column=1)
btnEquals=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='=',command=btnEquals, bg='powder blue').grid(row=4, column=2)
btnDivision=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='/',command=lambda:btnClick('/'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=4, column=3)

#================================================================================================================================

btnDecimal=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='.',command=lambda:btnClick('.'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=5, column=0)
btnPi=Button(window,padx=16,pady=14,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='π',command=lambda:btnClick(3.14), bg='powder blue').grid(row=5, column=1)

#================================================================================================================================

btnOpenBracket=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='(',command=lambda:btnClick('('), bg='powder blue').grid(row=5, column=2,)
btnClosedBracket=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text=')',command=lambda:btnClick(')'), bg='powder blue').grid(row=5, column=3,)

#================================================================================================================================

btnBackspace=Button(window,padx=16,pady=16,bd=10, fg='black',font=('arial', 20,'bold'), text='Backspace',command=backspace_b, bg='powder blue').grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=4, sticky=tk.W+tk.E)

# All code goes above this
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: What's the line of the error?

Comment: What makes you think that last function need `self` argument?

Comment: Please provide a mininal code and the full error.

Comment: Please post the full error traceback. That might be related to the fact that the `command` of the `Button` needs to be a function with no arguments and you pass it a one-argument function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is telling  you exactly what is wrong. You've written a function named `backspace_b` which  takes an argument named `self`. However, you are't passing that parameter when you call the function.

It looks like you copied it out of a class, but since it operates on a variable named `self.current` and you've neither defined `self` or a variable named `current`, it has no chance of working as defined. This is why you shouldn't just copy code from the internet without understanding how the code works.

Since you want to mimic the backspace key, you just need to remove the last character of your textvariable. Because you are also keeping the variable `global` as a copy of what is in the input field, you will need to delete the last character in it, too.

```
def backspace_b():
    global operator
    value = text_Input.get()
    if value:
        text_Input.set(value[:-1])
        operator = operator[:-1]
```

Comment: Thankyou for helping me! I am kind of new to python and some parts i do not know, so i try to find on the internet. This is why I came to stack overflow because I knew that people like you would answer my question. Thankyou for the solution :). Its quite silly actually what I have done know reading through what you said is wrong with my code :)

Comment: although if i use this for the button and then actually use the button, and then go and type in another number, it just adds the number i deleted on to the front of the new number. E.g: I backspace '2'. It goes back to showing nothing .Then I press '3'. It shows '23'. Any suggestions??

Comment: @Python_user_3: that is because you're copying the value from the entry widget into the global `operator` variable. You either need to adjust the `operator` variable, or change your logic so that you're always directly using the value in the entry widget.

Comment: Do you know how to code that, because I do not know how to?

Comment: Thanks for providing me with the code to make my calculator work :)

Answer (score 0):

When you use `self` in a function that is part of a class in python, it will refer to the instance of the class on which the method is called.
That happens implicitly, so if you use `self` like that, you do not need to explicitly assign a value.
You can't use `self` in that case here as your function is not part of a class.

The way you are using it, it is just a normal argument and if you call the function you need to assign a value to it. That value is missing and that is why you get the error.

You can read up on classes and `self` on the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: *You can't use `self` here, it can only be used in classes* - that's not very accurate. `self` is just a name - a convention - and has no real meaning for Python. It gets a special meaning when used as the first argument of instance methods. But still, it is just a name...

Comment: @Tomerikoo you're right, I edited the answer to make it more precise